# Getting signed request inside an Apex class

Tags: apex, json, canvas

How do i get a signed request field inside of an Apex class ?
I mean in .Net I can get it like this:

```
 string signedRequest = Request.Params["signed_request"];
```

Is there a similar "Request" object that i can use in Apex to get the "signed request" ?

Comment: For a Canvas App?

Comment: I know this is a weird scenario, but i have put the startup url for the canvas app as a public visual force site , and i want to get the signed request there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I have done this as well as a proof of concept...

If you set up a public VF page as the Canvas App, you should be able to read a parameter called signed_request from the visualforce page in your controller - loop through the params and you should see it there:

```
for (String s: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().keyset() ) {
system.debug(s + ':' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(s) );
}
```

If you assign that param to a string (e.g. s), you can then split the string

```
Public String sJson {get;set;}
String [] vsplit = s.split('\\.',0);
system.debug(vsplit[0]);
system.debug(vsplit[1]);

String encodedSig = vsplit[0];
String encodedEnvelope = vsplit[1];

Blob bEnv = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedEnvelope);
sJson = benv.toString(); 
system.debug(sJson); //This is the JSON Context you'll see referred to
```

Then on the page, you can access that String to use the sr

```
var sr = JSON.parse(sJson);
console.log(sr.context.links.chatterFeedsUrl);
```

Comment: Do you mean like this ? ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters('signed_request');

Comment: But its not a query string parameter right, so how do i get "signed_request" ? from the visualforce page ?

Comment: So I have a controller behind the page - see update above, the controller for my Canvas App VF page has thr parameter passed in from the calling VF page in my source Org

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC: I was trying to do the same, but came across some issues. The problem was that when the signed request was being sent from one org to the other, there is a redirect of URL which results in loss of the POST data. So, when my page finally shows up in the canvas, the signed request is not available. refreshSignedRequest() method is not available as yet (Part of Summer 14 release).
I have a question posted here for the same thing - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41615/can-i-build-a-canvas-app-using-salesforce