# Canvas app - verify signed request

Tags: apex, canvas, crypto

i am following the canvas app documentation to verify a signed request before using the parameters i am passing in the canvas app request. The canvas app is embedding a third party app in salesforce.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_unsigning_code_example.htm):

> 1. Receive the POST message that contains the initial signed request from
>    Salesforce.
> 2. Split the signed request on the first period. The result is two strings: the hashed Based64 context signed with the consumer secret
>    and the Base64 encoded context itself.
> 3. Use the HMAC SHA-256 algorithm to hash the Base64 encoded context and sign it using your consumer secret.
> 4. Base64 encode the string created in the previous step.
>
> 5.Compare the Base64 encoded string with the hashed Base64 context signed with the consumer secret you received in step 2.

I followed the below instructions

For step 1

```
Map<String, String> pageParams = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
     String sSignedReq = pageParams.get('signed_request');
```

For step 2:

```
 List<String> outputval = sSignedReq.split('\\.');
```

For step 3:

```
 Blob encodedEnvelopeHash = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(outputval[1])); 
String Privatekey = 'XXX';
blob signedvalue = Crypto.sign('RSA-SHA256', encodedEnvelopeHash, encodingutil.base64Decode(Privatekey));
```

I used open ssl to generate private key(PKCS8 format) for using it in crypto sign function

Link [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class):

Relevant code:

```
// Generate your own certificate - subject information is redacted
openssl req -x509 -nodes -subj "/C=XX/ST=XXX/L=XXX/CN=www.xxx.com" -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
// Output the private key onto the terminal in PKCS#8 format
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -outform PEM
```

For step 4:

```
String finalouput = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(signedvalue);
```

In step 5 i am doing a comparison and the 2 strings are never the same.

```
   if(outputval[0] == finalouput)
     system.debug('datamatchingok');
     else
      system.debug('datanotmatchingok');
```

What am i doing wrong? and how do i use consumer secret for verifying the signed request. Step 3 of documentation says we need to use that but i wasn't able to wrap my head around the documentation to understand where to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step click path to create a Salesforce Canvas App that uses a POSTed Signed Request to a Visualforce Page with an Apex Controller (and the Apex Controller successfully validates the Signed Request).

Note that in practice, I have always had Canvas Apps pointing to external platforms such as Heroku Express/Node, Java or Ruby. So I typically do the signed request validation in another language (e.g. javascript in Node.js). But to answer your specific question, I have included sample code for Visualforce and Apex and we will be validating the signed request using pure Apex. Also note that you do NOT need your own self-signed certificate or any use of openssl.

Here you go... this exercise will take about 15-30 minutes to complete. Let me know if you have any issue or questions and I'll see if I can assist further.

**Step 1 (use Classic)**

- Switch to Salesforce Classic -> Setup (to best align to this click path)

**Step 2 (create and configure a new Canvas Connected App)**
 -

- Create -> Apps -> **New Connected App**

  - Basic Information

    - **Connected App Name**: Canvas Test
    - **API Name**: Canvas_Test
    - **Contact Email**: (your email)
  - API (Enable OAuth Settings) (**This is needed to get the Secret Key**)

    - **Enable OAuth Settings**: checked
    - **Callback UR**L: https://localhost/callback-not-used
    - **Selected OAuth Scopes**: Full access (full)
    - **Require Secret for Web Server Flow**: checked (don't think this matters to example, but since it's checked by default, leave it)
  - Canvas App Settings

    - **Canvas Checkbox**: checked
    - **Canvas App URL**: normally external like heroku/node app, but for our demo purposes...
      https://mydomain--sandbox--c.cs16.visual.force.com/apex/canvas_page
      *( --- NOTICE THE "c.", I got this URL by navigating to /apex/canvas_page
      from my internal salesforce instance and then copy/pasted what it
      automatically changed to. We will create a Visualforce page soon, so you may have to come back to edit this if you can't guess it based on your environment)*
    - **Access Method**: Signed Request
    - **Locations**: (wherever you will embed the canvas app)
  - **Save**, **Continue**
  - *Remember, any changes to Connected App settings can take 10 full minutes to propagate*
- Connected App Details for "Canvas Test"

  - You should now have a Consumer Key and Consumer Secret (click to reveal)

    - **Consumer Key**: (CONSUMER KEY REDACTED)
    - **Consumer Secret**: (CONSUMER SECRET REDACTED)
- Create -> Apps -> Connected Apps

  - Manage -> **Edit Policies** Button

    - OAuth Policies

      - **Permitted Users**: Admin approved users are pre-authorized
      - **Save**
  - **Manage** -> (scroll down to relate lists) **Manage Profiles** Button (or Permission Sets)

    - **Add System Administrator** (or whatever is appropriate)

**Step 3 (create an Apex controller)**

- Developer Console

  - File -> New -> Apex Class

    - **Name**: canvas_page_ctlr
    - **Code**:

Apex

```
public class canvas_page_ctlr {

    public String rawOutputToScreen {get; set;}

    public canvas_page_ctlr(){
        //seriously, store this somewhere other than code (e.g. Private Custom Setting)
        String CLIENT_SECRET = 'INSERT_YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE'; 

        String signedRequest = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('signed_request');
        if(String.isNotBlank(signedRequest)){
            system.debug('signed_request: ' + signedRequest);
            List<String> signedRequestPieces = signedRequest.split('\\.'); //signed request pieces separated by a period (must escape the period in split regex)
            String contextSignedWithClientSecretByCanvasApp = signedRequestPieces[0]; //signed
            String contextEncoded  = signedRequestPieces[1]; //just encoded

            //Re-sign the encoded context with our pre-shared Canvas Connected App client secret...
            String contextReSignedWithClientSecretByThisController = 
                EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(contextEncoded), Blob.valueOf(CLIENT_SECRET)));

            //The signatures should match...
            if(contextSignedWithClientSecretByCanvasApp==contextReSignedWithClientSecretByThisController){
                //context valid and untampered...
                rawOutputToScreen = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(contextEncoded).toString();
            } else {
                //signature mismatch. don't trust context...
                rawOutputToScreen = 'Sorry Charlie! Not today.';
            }
        } else {
            //we didn't get a signed_request parameter in the POST body... show us what we got for demo purposes only...
            rawOutputToScreen = 'Error: ' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4 (create a Visualforce page)**
    - File -> New -> Visualforce Page
        - **Name**: canvas_page
        - **Code**:

Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="canvas_page_ctlr" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
<div style="border: solid 2px red; width: 400px; height: 400px; padding: 10px;">
    <p><u>Canvas via Signed Request Demo</u></p>
    <p>{!rawOutputToScreen}</p>
</div>
```

**Step 5 (preview the Canvas App and the parameters)**
 - Setup -> App Setup -> **Canvas App Previewer**
    -   Click on "Canvas Test"
    - You should see the Canvas App delivering a successfully verfied signed request in this format:

JSON context data structure sent with Canvas Signed Request

```
{
  "algorithm": "HMACSHA256",
  "issuedAt": -2038422695,
  "userId": "005-redacted",
  "client": {
    "refreshToken": null,
    "instanceId": "_:Canvas_Test:",
    "targetOrigin": "-redacted",
    "instanceUrl": "-redacted",
    "oauthToken": "00D-redacted"
  },
  "context": {
    "user": {
      "userId": "005-redacted",
      "userName": "b-redacted",
      "firstName": "First",
      "lastName": "Last",
      "email": "b-redacted",
      "fullName": "First Last",
      "locale": "en_US",
      "language": "en_US",
      "timeZone": "America\/Chicago",
      "profileId": "00e-redacted",
      "roleId": "00E-redacted",
      "userType": "STANDARD",
      "currencyISOCode": "USD",
      "profilePhotoUrl": "-redacted",
      "profileThumbnailUrl": "-redacted",
      "siteUrl": null,
      "siteUrlPrefix": null,
      "networkId": null,
      "accessibilityModeEnabled": false,
      "isDefaultNetwork": true
    },
    "links": {
      "loginUrl": "-redacted",
      "enterpriseUrl": "-redacted",
      "metadataUrl": "-redacted",
      "partnerUrl": "-redacted",
      "restUrl": "-redacted",
      "sobjectUrl": "-redacted",
      "searchUrl": "-redacted",
      "queryUrl": "-redacted",
      "recentItemsUrl": "-redacted",
      "chatterFeedsUrl": "-redacted",
      "chatterGroupsUrl": "-redacted",
      "chatterUsersUrl": "-redacted",
      "chatterFeedItemsUrl": "-redacted",
      "userUrl": "-redacted"
    },
    "application": {
      "name": "Canvas Test",
      "canvasUrl": "https:\/\/redacted--c.cs16.visual.force.com\/apex\/canvas_page",
      "applicationId": "06Pf-redacted",
      "version": "1.0",
      "authType": "SIGNED_REQUEST",
      "referenceId": "09H-redacted",
      "options": [

      ],
      "samlInitiationMethod": "None",
      "isInstalledPersonalApp": false,
      "namespace": "",
      "developerName": "Canvas_Test"
    },
    "organization": {
      "organizationId": "00D-redacted",
      "name": "B-redacted",
      "multicurrencyEnabled": false,
      "namespacePrefix": null,
      "currencyIsoCode": "USD"
    },
    "environment": {
      "referer": null,
      "locationUrl": "-redacted",
      "displayLocation": null,
      "sublocation": null,
      "uiTheme": "Theme3",
      "dimensions": {
        "width": "800px",
        "height": "900px",
        "maxWidth": "1000px",
        "maxHeight": "2000px",
        "clientWidth": "1123px",
        "clientHeight": "80px"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "my_custom_param_1": "if_provided_from_canvas_location",
        "my_custom_param_2": "if_provided_from_canvas_location",
      },
      "record": {

      },
      "version": {
        "season": "SUMMER",
        "api": "43.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers,

Bryan Isbell

Salesforce Certified Technical Architect, CISSP

Comment: Thanks @Bryan, I will check and get back to you later today

Comment: just a follow up question, when do we need to use a digital signature vs mac based crypto verification?. I got confused by the third line of documentation which says sign the request using consumer secret . Thats why i was trying to use the crypto sign method.

Comment: Nice. Verifying the Signed Request in Apex was something I didn't get around to completing in [Can I embed a Salesforce app, via Canvas, in another org?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/42298/102)

Comment: Great answer. Thx! Curious to know when is the 'Consumer Key' used? The code only uses 'Consumer Secret' for the verification.